# Truffle returns no code at address after contract update

Tags: truffle, ganache, ethers.js

etherjs (5.0) is used to deployed a smart contract `Hello.sol`. Here is the js code (truffle 5.1.52/ganache CLI 6.12.1):

```
  import { ContractFactory, ethers } from "ethers";

  let privateKey = "0xf43608a210da70d40115ad23526e50f2a502c018aeffd56477fcbe44119b53cc"; //<<==private key from ganache-cli
  let wallet = new ethers.Wallet(privateKey);  //address of the wallet
  console.log("wallet : ", wallet);
  //deploy
  const factory = new ContractFactory(abi, bytecode, signer); //<<==abi, bytecode, signer defined before
  const contract = await factory.deploy(wallet.address);
  console.log("contract deployed : ", contract);
  console.log("contract address : ", contract.address);
  // The transaction that the signer sent to deploy
  contract.deployTransaction;
  // Wait until the transaction is mined
  contract.deployTransaction.wait();
```

The execution of code above generates the output on `ganache-cli -b 3`:

```
  Transaction: 0x5c626a276ba9ddf0b0b69c4fab774b5ac2e8026fe7dd0bb149b4939a2b1ca25d
  Contract created: 0xaec5a7f864e3e5e42554b5d645f62ba07add7517
  Gas usage: 122107
  Block Number: 1075
  Block Time: Sun Nov 15 2020 13:15:03 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)

eth_blockNumber
eth_chainId
eth_getTransactionReceipt
```

The contract is deployed at the address of `0xaec5a7f864e3e5e42554b5d645f62ba07add7517`. Then launching `truffle development` and `hello = await Hello.at("0xaec5a7f864e3e5e42554b5d645f62ba07add7517")` returns the instance of the contract deployed. The problem is that after `Hello.sol` is updated with addition of 2 functions, now the `hello = await...` returns an error:

```
truffle(develop)> hello = await Hello.at("0xaec5a7f864e3e5e42554b5d645f62ba07add7517")
Uncaught:
Error: Cannot create instance of Hello; no code at address 0xaec5a7f864e3e5e42554b5d645f62ba07add7517
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at Function.at (C:\D\code\js\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\contract\lib\contract\constructorMethods.js:74:1)
    at Object.checkCode (C:\D\code\js\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\contract\lib\utils\index.js:265:1)
```

Here is the step the `Hello.sol` was updated:

1. function `setValue` and `getValue` were added to the contract in remix
2. compile successfully with abi and bytecode
3. update the `Hello.sol` in VS code
4. run `truffle compile` successfully
5. After deploying the contract in VS code, use the contract address returned in `ganache` to make connection in `truffle development`

What is wrong causing the contract is not at the address returned by `ganache` after update?

UPDATE:here is the part of the truffle-config.js:

```
networks: {
      development: {
        host: "localhost",
        port: 8545,  //testing
        network_id: "*" // Match any network id
      }
    },
```

Comment: Is truffle connected to the same ganache instance? Check the networks section in `truffle-config.js` file matches ganache instance.

Comment: Just updated with networks:development in truffle-config.js. It is connected to port 8545 on localhost.

Comment: Check again if you are using the right network develop != development. To pass the correct network is something like this: `truffle console --network development`.